# How take the defference between sum of column values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two simple tables. `tbl_purchased` and  `tbl_sold`

tbl_purchased

```
col_item_name col_no_of_items
Fan                         5
Builb                       5
Oven                        5
Fan                         2
Builb                       2
```

tbl_sold

```
col_item_name col_no_of_items
Fan                         3
Oven                        1
```

I need to take

1. SUM of items purchased, GROUP BY item name.
2. SUM of items sold, GROUP BY item name.

I can do that using following queries separately.

```
SELECT col_item_name, SUM(col_no_of_items)
FROM tbl_purchased
GROUP BY col_item_name;
```

and

```
SELECT col_item_name, SUM(col_no_of_items)
FROM tbl_sold
GROUP BY col_item_name;
```

now I need to take the current stock.

[image]

That means,
(SUM of purchased items - SUM of sold items) GROUP BY item name.

Can I do that using SINGLE sql query?

Comment: You really need to have keys on your tables. What would happen if you want to buy 2 more fans?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. You can do it in a single query; read up on joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: I suspect that you will find the practice of prefixing tables with 'tbl' and columns with 'col' very tiring very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like bellow (might need to adjust it though):

```
SELECT p.col_item_name, SUM(p.col_no_of_items) - SUM (s.col_no_of_items)
FROM tbl_purchased p
left join tbl_sold s on p.col_item_name=s.col_item_name
GROUP BY p.col_item_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

```
SELECT col_item_name, SUM(no_purchased) - SUM(no_sold) AS item_stock
FROM
   (SELECT col_item_name, col_no_of_items AS no_purchased, 0 AS no_sold
    FROM tbl_purchased
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col_item_name, 0 AS no_purchased,col_no_of_items AS no_sold)
GROUP BY col_item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly work for you

SELECT p.`name`, ((SELECT SUM(NO) FROM `purcahse` WHERE `name`=p.name)-(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(NO),0) FROM `sell` WHERE `name`=s.name))
 remaining FROM `purcahse` p LEFT JOIN `sell` s ON p.name=s.name GROUP BY p.name;

enjoy thanks :)

Comment: What's `purcahse`

Comment: purcahse is ur purchase table and sale is ur sale table

Comment: It's not mine, but why not call it `purchase` or `tbl_purchased`

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: join your first table expression (need to give the summarization a name e.g. `col_no_of_items_purchased`) to `tbl_curent_stock`, then do simple arithmetic. You should also consider items that haven't been purchased by anti-joining. Then `UNION` the two together:

```
SELECT col_item_name,
       col_no_of_items - col_no_of_items_purchased AS col_no_of_items
FROM tbl_curent_stock
     NATURAL JOIN
     ( SELECT col_item_name,
              SUM(col_no_of_items) AS col_no_of_items_purchased
         FROM tbl_purchased
        GROUP
           BY col_item_name ) AS t
UNION
SELECT col_item_name, col_no_of_items
  FROM tbl_curent_stock
 WHERE col_item_name NOT IN ( SELECT col_item_name
                                FROM tbl_purchased );
```